# Dynamically update polyline with new map click with reactjs and leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm new to reactjs and leaflet and working on building a "route mapping" application. Currently, I have one to two points in an array of points (mapPoints) that updates each time I click on the map. (ie. the markers update to reflect new map click.) These are a state in my class (`this.state.mapPoints`), which is updated via `setState` each time the map is clicked. I am trying to dynamically update a polyline between these two points each time the map is clicked. I figured that by calling a function to return the new marker positions as the polyline positions if there are sufficient points using `this.state.mapPoints`.

While the function reads in `this.state.mapPoints` correctly, and is therefore updating correctly, the polyline will not dynamically update, and remains drawn where it was initially drawn between the first set of two points. How can I update the polyline to be drawn between the newly updated `mapPoints` state? (I have summarized pieces of the code via comments for simplicity.)

```
//code for imports, etc, here


constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.addMarker = this.addMarker.bind(this);
    this.getClientLocation = this.getClientLocation.bind(this);
    this.getMapPoints = this.getMapPoints.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        mapPoints: [this.getClientLocation()],
    };
}


/*

other render() code is here to render leaflet map and webpage/application

*/


renderLeafletMap() {
    return (
        <Map
            center={this.state.mapPoints[0]}
            zoom={this.state.zoom}
            onClick={this.addMarker}
            style={{height: MAP_STYLE_LENGTH, maxWidth: MAP_STYLE_LENGTH}}>
            <TileLayer url={MAP_LAYER_URL} attribution={MAP_LAYER_ATTRIBUTION}/>
            {this.getMarker(this.state.mapPoints)}
            <Polyline color={'red'}
                      positions={this.getMapPoints(this.state.mapPoints)}/>
        </Map>
    )
}

getMapPoints(markerPositions) {
    console.log(markerPositions); //this line successfully reflects the current state of mapPoints when the application runs
    if (markerPositions.length >= 2)
        return markerPositions;
    else
        return [[0,0],[0,0]];
}


addMarker(mapClickInfo) {
    let updatedArray = this.state.mapPoints;
    if(updatedArray[1]){
        updatedArray[0] = updatedArray[1];
        updatedArray[1] = mapClickInfo.latlng;
    }else {
        updatedArray[1] = mapClickInfo.latlng;
    }
    this.setState({mapPoints: updatedArray});
}



getClientLocation() {
    if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        alert.show("Your browser does not support geolocation.");
    } else{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                const currentLocation = L.latLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                let updatedArray = this.state.mapPoints;
                updatedArray[0] = currentLocation;
                this.setState({mapPoints: updatedArray});
            }
        );
    }
}

/* 

other code to set initial mapPoints, etc, here

*/
```

Comment: can you make a simple demo to reproduce the issue? where is `getClientLocation` function?

Comment: I didn't include getClientLocation function because it just gets the initial client location from the current browser, so it's not applicable to the issue. However, I have included a picture of the issue and updated the code. The issue is that the polyline does not track with the marker updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly mutating the state that is why you do not see the expected result.

Your `addMarker` function should be:

```
addMarker = mapClickInfo => {
    let updatedArray = [...this.state.mapPoints]; //create a copy of the mapPoints array and then modify it
    if (updatedArray[1]) {
      updatedArray[0] = updatedArray[1]; 
      // also here you want to extract the coordinates and assign them to your index 1 on your mapPoints array, mapClickInfo.latlng is an {} and you want to have an array as index 1 on your mapPoints array
      updatedArray[1] = [mapClickInfo.latlng.lat, mapClickInfo.latlng.lng];
    } else {
      // here the same
      updatedArray[1] = [mapClickInfo.latlng.lat, mapClickInfo.latlng.lng];
    }
    this.setState({ mapPoints: updatedArray });
  };
```

Also you do a similar thing in your `getClientLocation` function. Should be likes this:

```
getClientLocation = () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      alert.show("Your browser does not support geolocation.");
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        const {
          coords: { latitude, longitude }
        } = position;
        const mapPoints = [...this.state.mapPoints];
        mapPoints[0] = [latitude, longitude];
        this.setState({ mapPoints });
      });
    }
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-update-polyline-with-new-map-click-with-reactjs-and-leaflet-etxvh)

Comment: Okay thank you so much! So when the state is mutated directly, ReactJS does not necessarily read it as an "update"?

Comment: Also I'm still a bit confused on why the "current location" was changed to const { coords: {latitude, longitude}} = position? What does the curly brace for the "const" do? Just change the format of the lat, lng?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I redefine the functions as callback functions in my code (ie. addMarker = mapClickInfo => {} instead of addMarker(mapClickInfo){}) my build fails, saying it is an unexpected token, though I'm not sure why. I thought callback functions should work in place of a regular function.

Comment: When the state is mutated directly react does not rerender the component because it cannot compare the previous with the next state values in the virtual Dom. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: You need to use arrow functions to avoid binding this on the constructor for every method in your class.